# Conditional SELECT from ACCESS

Tags: sql, ms-access, oledb

I'm using OleDb to query an Access database

I have an SQL which selects a number of columns from 3 joined tables.  it works fine until I try to include a CASE stament or equivalent.

I want to return TableB.col2 if TableA.col1 is NULL, otherwise I want TableA.col1.

sample data as requested:

```
table A
col 1 - NULL
col 2 - 78

table B
col 1 - 53
col 2 - 12
```

if the above exists, TableA.col1 is NULL so I want TableB.col2: 12

```
table A
col 1 - 35
col 2 - 78

table B
col 1 - 53
col 2 - 12
```

if the above exists, TableA.col1 is not NULL so I'll return it: 35

My SQL already joins 3 tables and returns 100 columns.  This is just adding an extra column onto the list.

I have tried:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN TableA.col1 IS NULL THEN TableB.col2 ELSE TableA.col1 AS col
```

which gives A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: IErrorInfo.GetDescription failed with E_FAIL(0x80004005)and

```
Nz(TableA.col1, TableB.col2) AS col
```

gives me: A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: Undefined function 'NZ' in expression 
and these two:

```
IIF(TableA.col1 is NULL, TableB.col2,TableA.col1) AS col 
IIF(isNull(TableA.col1), TableB.col2,TableA.col1) AS col
```

both give the rather generic error message: A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll
Additional information: No value given for one or more required parameters.

Comment: Please edit your question with sample data and desired results.  It is not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: I want to return TableB.col2 if TableA.col1 is NULL, otherwise I want TableA.col1; sample data added as requested

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is valid Access SQL syntax:

```sql
IIF(TableA.col1 is NULL, TableB.col2, TableA.col1) AS col
```

The error message, *"No value given for one or more required parameters"*, indicates Access doesn't recognize something in the query as an object, function, or SQL keyword. Usually that happens due to a spelling error.

Test your `SELECT` statement as a new query in the Access query designer.  When you attempt to run it from there, Access will present an input dialog which asks you to supply a value for the first parameter it finds.  Notice that dialog includes the parameter's name.  If that doesn't pinpoint the problem, show us your query's SQL and tell us the name of the parameter(s) Access identifies.

Comment: thank you, it was useful to know I was using the correct syntax and there was a typo.